# Higher or not PHP

Tags: php

I have a database with an field calls balance. This is €10,000. I also have a field that calls limit this is €7,500. What I want is when my field balance is bigger than my field limit, then echo: "Please, pay before start.";

I tried this:

```
<?php
if ($row['balance'] > $row['limit']){
echo "Please, pay before start.";
}
?>
```

It doesn't work. Maybe because the comma in the numbers? How can I check this?

Comment: If you are storing proces as strings with thousand-separators and currency symbols, that's not good practice - for the reason you state. Store prices as numbers, and do the prettifying as part of the rendering process.

Comment: wow! do you use strings to store money?

Comment: NEVER store money as floats, they are inaccurate. store only as whole numbers.

Comment: @halfer: `float` for money is not better data type then `string`

Comment: For efficiency when storing a currency value, you can store them by their cent value. This makes comparing easy too, and you don't need to worry about precision loss. Do some string-solution (no arithmetics) when you print the values.

Answer (score 3):

This idea is not good, you should try  decimal/numeric type in your database. You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)  for display your prefer format. then you can easily check you condition

Comment: I deleted my answer. This is a better solution.

Comment: Yes, although see @Atle's comment about using integers.

Comment: @halfer thanks. I understand this and edit my answer. This is really important to understand. also I read mysql doc [Problems with float](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html) and [Fixed point types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the number out of the currency value to be able to properly compare them:

```
$balance = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $row['balance'] ));
$limit = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $row['limit'] ));

if ($balance > $limit) {
    echo "Please, pay before start.";
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/57727)

Comment: Non-regex solutions would be faster

Comment: Not sure performance is going to be an issue here. Also regexes aren't necessarily slow.

Comment: +1, though this fixes the problem at the wrong point. Currency should be stored as numbers and only in the view should it get commas and currency symbols.

Comment: @DrupalStarter: The above solution should work *just* fine, but as halfer said above, you shouldn't store currency values as strings -- store them as numbers. That way, you could avoid having to deal with all these nasty replaces :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks. It is just a small project. Your solution works fine. Thanks again!